# Loading a specific image using the name of a variable handed to a function

Tags: c#, image

So I am wanting to load an image with the use of a function that receives as a string the name of the image it needs to load and then have it load it however I cannot get this to work as I think the program is simply trying to load the variable name rather that the the string it stores(which is the actual name of the image). Sorry if that's badly worded hopefully my code clears up what I mean.

```
bool FlagDisplay(PictureBox team, string teamName)//Displays the flag of the team that was selected
{
    if (teamName == "Canada")
    {
        team.Image = Properties.Resources.Canada;
    }
    else if (teamName == "New Zealand")
    {
        team.Image = Properties.Resources.NZ;
    }
    else if (teamName == "South Africa")
    {
        team.Image = Properties.Resources.RSA;
    }
    return (true);
}
```

I want my code to work more like

```
bool FlagDisplay(PictureBox team, string teamName)//Displays the flag of the team that was selected
{
    team.Image = Properties.Resources.teamName;
}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: You can't do anything based on the name of the variable passed to a method. What if a variable is not used, but only an expression, like `teamName + " team"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var imageToShow = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(teamName);
```

imageToShow will be a System.Drawing.Bitmap.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/963f81yd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That almost made it work. However now teh only image that will load is the one for Canada. Their flag image file is on the top of teamFlag.images

Comment: Sorry, there still needs to be a conversion between Team Name and the resource name, or name the resource names the same as the team names in the resource file.

Comment: Yep I found it dumb mistake on my part. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

A PictureBox only contains one Picture.  If you want to change the image that it is displaying , then you need to pass an actual Image to it, not just a string.

so , try this:

```
public void FlagDisplay(PictureBox team, string teamName)//Displays the flag of the team that was selected
{
    // note here you probably need to add .jpg or .png to the teamName
    var imageToShow = new Bitmap(teamName); // this takes filename
    team.Image = (Image) imageToShow;
}
```

Comment: That throws up an parameter is not valid exception. I think you are on the correct track for what i'm trying to do but any idea how to fix the exception?

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to code your `FlagDisplay` method like this:

```
bool FlagDisplay(PictureBox team, string teamName)
{
    var images = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "Canada", Properties.Resources.Canada },
        { "New Zealand", Properties.Resources.NZ },
        { "South Africa", Properties.Resources.RSA },
    };
    if (images.ContainsKey(teamName))
    {
        team.Image = new Bitmap(images[teamName]);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The advantage with this approach is that you can pull the dictionary out of the method and build it dynamically to handle different countries or image locations without necessarily needing to recompile your `FlagDisplay` source.

If that causes an error then you don't have full image paths in your resources.